# How do you 'adapt' a class member that is a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, adapter

So I'm trying to create an adapter where the adapter inherits from the class it is trying emulate. The constructor takes an instance of the class that will be adapted and then maps properties so that the two are piping info through each other, pretty standard, i think. However, one of the members happens to be a list of another type that must be adapted as well. Is there a pattern for this??

Here's an example:

```
public class Contract.ClassA
{
    public List<Contract.ListMemberClass> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Domain.ClassA
{
    public List<Domain.ListMemberClass> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Contract.ListMemberClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Domain.ListMemberClass
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
}

// adapters

public class DomainClassAdapter : Domain.ClassA
{
    private readonly Contract.ClassA _input;

    public DomainClassAdapter(Contract.ClassA input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    public List<Domain.ListMemberClass> Members {
    {
        get
        {
            // ???
        }
        set
        {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

So my first instinct for the getter is to create yet another adapter for that list member, new that up and return that. And then do the same thing going the other direction for the setter. So I could end up with umpteen billion adapters.

Is that the only way to do this, or is there some other pattern, trick, technology, etc to address this scenario??

Comment: Is the adapter also responsible for getting things back to the `Contract` namespace models?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be the same adapter, but that would be the next step, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems reasonable to me that the `Domain.ListMemberClass` would have an adapter. However, I'm not really aware of any pattern for this.

Assuming you only need to convert between the `Domain` and `Contract` namespace when doing a server call, I'd actually suggest putting the behavior in the constructor and leaving the property auto-implemented.

```
public DomainClassAdapter(Contract.ClassA input)
{
  _input = input;
  this.Members = _input.Members.Select(x => new DomainListMemberAdapter(x));
}
```

If you don't want to create a bunch of clutter from adapters, it'd be simple enough (especially with just two properties) to create `Domain.ListMemberClass` instances inside the LINQ statement, instead of adapter instances.

If you don't want to have a constructor call that could be expensive, you could do a cached approach for the property:

```
private List<Domain.ListMemberClass> _members;
public List<Domain.ListMemberClass> Members {
{
  get
  {
    if(_members == null)
    {
      // Populate _members from _input
    }
    return _members;
  }
  set
  {
    // No special behavior necessary, I think
  }
}
```

Both examples assume you'd call some method that would convert everything to the `Contract` namespace models when necessary. I'm a bit afraid I may have missed the point of the adapter pattern though, so please let me know if I have, in fact, missed the point.

Comment: Yeah I think we did kinda miss on that one. I was trying to avoid the cross from an adapter to a mapper. It may be that the only options are to create adapters for everything, or build them via linq. I don't like either option so I was hoping there was something I didn't know that would be the magical solution. It could also be that I need to re-evaluate the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: Yea, the biggest challenge I think is that once you pass back a `List<Domain.ListMemberClass>` it's a new list, so something likes `Add()` won't magically transfer things to the `Contract` copy held in the `DomainClassAdapter`. I think you'd have to write an adapter that also implements `IList` for this to work.